# найти максимальный массив, из которого можно удалить некоторые элементы, чтобы получились другой данный массив

Tags: c

Дан массив А длины N, и K массивов M1,...,Mk длин m1,...,mk. Требуется найти наибольший по длине массив среди M1,...,Mk , который может быть получен из массива A при помощи удаления каких-либо элементов массива A. Все данные читаются из файлов. Все массивы M1,...,Mk записаны по порядку в одном файле: первые два числа в файле - кол-во элементов SizeM, и кол-во массивов K. Далее, идут массивы: первое число - длина массива Mi, далее сам массив Mi. Написал такой код на си, но когда запускаю он не решает задачу, а возвращает рандомное число. Хотелось бы узнать, на что стоит обратить внимание, чтобы пофиксить это недорозумение.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int Process(int* dataA, int* dataM, int n, int index);
int ReadArray(FILE* file, int* data, int size);

int ReadArray(FILE* file, int* data, int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(fscanf(file, "%d", data + i) != 1){
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int Process(int* dataA, int* dataM, int n, int index){
    int tmp1 = dataM[index];
    int tmp2 = index;
    int ind = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = (tmp2+1); j < (tmp2+tmp1+1); j++){
            if(dataA[i] == dataM[j]){
                ind++;
                tmp2 = j-1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(ind == n){
        return tmp1;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

int main(void){
    FILE* finA;
    FILE* finM;
    int* dataA;
    int* dataM;
    int n;
    int k;
    int sizeM;
    int index = 0;
    int indexmax1 = -1;
    int indexmax2 = 0;

    if((finA = fopen("inputA.txt", "rt")) == NULL){
        printf("Can't open input file!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(fscanf(finA, "%d", &n) != 1){
        printf("Can't read size!\n");
        fclose(finA);
        return -1;
    }

    if(n < 1){
        printf("Incorrect size!\n)");
        fclose(finA);
        return -1;
    }

    if((dataA = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int))) == NULL){
        printf("Can't allocate memory!\n");
        fclose(finA);
        return -1;
    }

    if(ReadArray(finA, dataA, n) < 0){
        printf("Can't read array!\n");
        free(dataA);
        fclose(finA);
        return -1;
    }



    if((finM = fopen("inputM.txt", "rt")) == NULL){
        printf("Can't open input file!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(fscanf(finM, "%d", &sizeM) != 1){
        printf("Can't read size!\n");
        fclose(finM);
        return -1;
    }

    if(fscanf(finM, "%d", &k) != 1){
        printf("Can't read count of files!\n");
        fclose(finM);
        return -1;
    }

    if(n < 1){
        printf("Incorrect size!\n)");
        fclose(finM);
        return -1;
    }

    if((dataA = (int*) malloc(sizeM * sizeof(int))) == NULL){
        printf("Can't allocate memory!\n");
        fclose(finM);
        return -1;
    }

    if(ReadArray(finM, dataM, sizeM) < 0){
        printf("Can't read array!\n");
        free(dataM);
        fclose(finM);
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        if(indexmax1 < Process(dataA, dataM, n, index)){
            indexmax1 = Process(dataA, dataM, n, index);
            indexmax2 = index;
        }
        index += Process(dataA, dataM, n, index)+1;
    }

    if(indexmax1 != -1){
        for(int i = indexmax2; i < (indexmax2+indexmax1+1); i++){
            printf("%d\n", dataM[i]);
        }
        free(dataA);
        free(dataM);
        return 0;
    }

    else{
        printf("There are no need sequences!");
        free(dataA);
        free(dataM);
        return -1;

    }
}
```

Comment: непонятна переменная `int tmp1 = dataM[index];` в `Process`. присваиваете данные, используете как индекс? *и имя у неё, так-себе*

Comment: Условие кривовато. Во втором файле `k` - количество массивов, а `SizeM` - что такое?

Comment: @DmitryK SizeM завожу, чтобы в последствии выделить память для массива с массивами M. Я предполагаю, что это самое первое число в файле, которая равна количеству оставшихся элементов, после того как я считал SizeM и k( два самых первых числа)

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Вам нужно только количество массивов. Потом в каждой строке идет размер массива и данные этого массива. SizeM - непонятная лишняя информация.

Comment: @DmitryK т.е. мне придется создавать k раз новые массивы специально для каждого из Mi?

Comment: Теперь понял - вы храните все массивы в одном одномерном массиве. Места немного сохранили конечно, но сложность кода повысилась.

Comment: Не нужно портить свой вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы два раза выделяете память на один указатель.

```
// первый раз
if((dataA = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
{}
// второй раз
if((dataA = (int*) malloc(sizeM * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
{}
```

А массив `dataM` остается невыделенным. И вы пытаетесь туда записывать значения.
Ещё один момент - вы уверены, что оптимизатор отработает как надо и в этом куске функция `Process()` вызовется 1 раз, а не 3?

```
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    if(indexmax1 < Process(dataA, dataM, n, index))
    {
        indexmax1 = Process(dataA, dataM, n, index);
        indexmax2 = index;
    }
    index += Process(dataA, dataM, n, index)+1;
}
// Может проще
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{ 
    int tmp = Process(dataA, dataM, n, index);
    if(indexmax1 < tmp)
    {}
```

Ну и последнее (возможно самое главное) функция `int Process()` делает не то, что требуется в условии задачи. Вам нужно, чтобы массив `Mi` являлся подмножеством массива `A`. А на самом деле функция считает количество совпадений элементов между массивами в штуках.
Пример `A[] = {1,2,3}` и `M[] = { 1, 1, 1};`. Результатом вашей функции будет число 3, которое совпадет с размером массива `A`, что вы почему-то считаете правильным ответом.
По условию задачи, массив М будет меньше или равен массиву А и совпадений между элементами будет меньше (или равно).
Ещё нельзя забывать, что элементы могут повторяться, как в массиве А, так и в М.

Comment: Спасибо! Исправил на dataM, вроде работает.

Comment: Работает, но неправильно. :) И спасибо здесь - принятый ответ.

Comment: я понял, что я не правильно прочитал условие. я решал задачу наоборот: так чтобы из Mi можно было получить A.

Comment: И тоже неправильно. Пример в ответе работает в обе стороны.

Comment: :) уже понял, что даже так не работает. спасибо!

Comment: Проще конечно на `c++` взять контейнеры делать множества и проверять на пересечение. Но если просто на `c`, то тогда вариант решения: 1. Сортируете массивы. 2. Если массив М больше массива A - пропускаем. 3. Ставим 2 указателя в начала массивов. Двигаемся по А пока не найдем совпадения. если A[i] больше M[j] - выход, значит в А такого значения нет. 4. Если дошли до конца М - значит ОК.

Comment: Я понял, что вы решаете задачу так, что М подмножество А (не совсем, тк элементы повторяются). Значит порядок элементов в них не важен, поэтому и сортируем. Но мне надо решить учитывая порядок. То есть я буквально, если у меня есть массив А и я вычеркну просто какие-то числа в нем, то получу М ничего не переставляя.

Comment: В условии ничего не сказано про порядок следования элементов. Если порядок важен (если вы ищете последовательность, а не множество), то тогда да - сортировать не надо. Ну и всё равно решается за 1 проход, а не цикл в цикле (n * m).